# how to determine whether a point is above or below a polygon,not inside of the polygon?

Tags: polygon, point

I am taking Computer Graphics course.In 3D,I have a point and a polygon and I want to determine this point is located above or below my polygon.Thanks for your replies,in advance.

Comment: Its not clear if you are asking for a 2D or 3D algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If above or below the plane on which the polygon is resting will do, you can compare the dot product of the point onto the plane normal and that of any point on the plane. Or look at the sign of the dot product between the normal and a vector from a point on the plane to the point, if you prefer.

To check whether it is actually 'above' or 'below' in the sense of being directly above or below (ie, not off to the side somewhere) then do a point in polygon by projecting the whole thing into 2d along the normal and then a distance along normal test.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of above and below, let me first talk about the easy case:

- If you think of above/below in terms of a global direction (typically the y-axis or z-axis), just compare the values on that axis.

Ok, now the more difficult interpretation: On which side of the polygon is the point.

- Unless it is complanar you cannot decide it for the polygon at once. So if it is non-complanar you have to tesselate it into triangles and decide for each of them.
- For a triangle you can decide whether a point is above or below it (in 3D), first calculate the cross product of 2 vectors that make up the sides of the triangle; this will define a *direction* (= the definition of "above" and "below"), this depends on the order in which you use those 2 vectors so be careful. Then calculate the dot-product of the new vector (which is called the perpendicular of that triangle) and the difference-vector of the point-to-test and the triangle-base.

Comment: Now,I understand better what you mean.Thanks.

Comment: you have not rated and not accepted yet. anything else you want to know?

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow,I was following the site,but I was finding answers from old topics.Sorry,I did not know the vote and rate appl. in this site.